# Adding new software to Aptana

Tags: aptana

I'm using Aptana IDE which is like (Eclipse)
I want to install new plugins using Help > install new software
and add the following link

http://www.spket.com/update/

It views the following error:

contacting software sites has encountered a problem 
No repository found at http://www.spket.com/update/

What is the problem>

Comment: The URL that you have doesn't have a repository for the software you want?

Comment: Its ok .. I've found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my question

http://drfits.com/2011/11/13/eclipse-contacting-software-sites-has-encountered-a-problem/